# How to get selected value from drop downlist in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, todo

i am not able to get the value from drop list
the value that i am getting are wrong, they are reverse if i click complete it will show incomplete in console and vice verse

```
const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setStatus(e.target.value);
    console.log(status);

<select className="formList" onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value="incomplete">Incomplete</option>
          <option value="complete">Complete</option>
        </select>
  };
```

i am expecting to get correct values

Comment: please post your full code

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
const [status,setStatus]=useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
setStatus(e.target.value);
};

useEffect(() => {
console.log(status);
}, [status]);

return (
<select className="formList" 
onChange={handleChange}>
<option value="incomplete">
Incomplete</option>
<option 
value="complete">Complete</option>
</select>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).